# Perfect participle of " While Studying late at night, he fell asleep"

Tags: adjectives, perfect-constructions

Would it be:

> Having studied late at night, he slept.

Or something else?

Comment: Neither the sentence in the title nor the examples in the text make much sense. Can you give us more context about where you found them?

Comment: Ok corrected and edited now. And got reply from jeff

Comment: They have different meanings. The example in the title means they happened at the same time. The example in the body of the question means he slept **because** he studied late at night

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Studying late at night, he slept

does not make any sense because the actions were not concurrent.

> Having studied late at night, he slept

is grammatical, but not common. In English, we tend not to rely solely on tense to specify sequence. So more common would be

> After studying, he slept.

The sequence is specified without any need for a perfect construction.